# Bootstrap 4 checkbox plus radio overlap (in modal)

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with my code for hours, and it looks like I need some external eyes on it.

I am trying to get a checkbox followed by two radio buttons in vertical alignment, inside a modal, with Bootstrap 4. I have a similar set of buttons working inside the same modal and I just needed to replicate the setup. Yet this time the radio buttons come overlapping on the checkbox.

I have checked the documentation, and multiple questions in here, to no avail.

Here's the code I am using:

```
            <div class="upToClass">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="checkUpToPage">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="checkUpToPage">
                      Up to
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <!-- radio buttons to choose the end page -->
                  <div id="upToPage-choice">
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="check-no-page-1" id="check-no-page" value="P_no" checked>
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="check-no-page" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Insert the number of the last page where the repetition shall apply.">
                        Page number
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="check-choose-page-1" id="check-choose-page" value="man_P">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="check-choose-page" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Choose manually the last page where the repetition should apply.">
                        Choose manually
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
```

While the same code works above in the modal, it overlaps just a few lines down:
[image: First three lines work ok, second set of three overlaps :/]

Comment: a jsfiddle would be helpful. Your shared code doesn't help anything as you didn't share your structure, nor your styles.

Comment: By creating the fiddle I found the error.... There was a `"` just in front of the first `input` tag which was creating the mess. Thanks @DavidLiang

Comment: I was going to bug you about that extra " but I thought it was just typo. Good that you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pfft. I spent a few hours trying to figure out what was wrong, and what was creating the mess was a simple `"` in front of the first `input` tag. 
Thanks @DavidLiang for asking me for a jsfiddle, which ended up in me finding the bug.

(I got it because the fiddle was showing a different reaction to the bug:
[image]
Pasting the code from Atom in the fiddle had added spaces at the end of most attributes. It was adding to the trouble, yet it helped me finding the real one.)